# Deluge function to get a Postcode and put the street name and city into the Address field on Zoho CRM

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm trying to write a code that'll automatically run when a contact is created. It'll take the postcode and use that with my Google Geocoding API to pull the street and city, and put that in the Address field.

```
leadDetails = zoho.crm.getRecordById("ARCH_Concept_Ltd",input.leadId);

// Make API call to Google Maps Geocoding API
api_key = "API_Number";
postcode = ifnull(leadDetails.get("Postcode"),"");
api_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+postcode+"&key="+api_key;
response = http.get(api_url.toURL());

// Parse the response to extract the street address
data = json.parse(response.getContent());
address = data.results[0].formatted_address;

// Store the address in the "Address" field
mp = Map();
mp.put("Address",address);
update = zoho.crm.updateRecord("ARCH_Concept_Ltd",leadId.toLong(),mp);
info mp;
info update;
```

I'm getting the following error:

Failed to save the function
Syntax error. Expecting executeshellscript task,expression,invokeurl task or 'invokeintegration'. Found '['. Line Number: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it is expecting `executeshellscript task,expression,invokeurl task or 'invokeintegration'.`.

Although it says the error is at the `'[' on line 11`, that is just where the interpreter finally gave up.

This line: `response = http.get(api_url.toURL());` can be replaced with zoho-Deluge's `invokeurl` command so give that a try.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I've replaced it and it's working now